# Objective-C prepareForSegue Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am using the prepareForSegue with my `UISplitViewController` and I have a `NSMutableDictionary` populating the `UITableView` with sections. What I am trying to do is pass the value of the selected value in the selected section to the method in my `detailViewController`, this is what I got so far:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *strPOIndex = [self.tableData[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Vendor"];



            LHContactsDetail *controller = (LHContactsDetail *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

            [controller setDetailItem:strPOIndex];
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
        }

    }
```

but the issue with this, it returns the numbered item of the first section. Example, if I click on section 2 item 1, it returns section 1 item 1, if I click on section 3 item 2, it returns section 1 item 2. I hope this makes sense. THis is how I am populating my tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [contactSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionContacts = [contactDirectoryFinal objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *contacts = [[sectionContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Vendor_Name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = contacts;

    return cell;

}
```

How can I get the correct value to send to my `detailController` method ?

Comment: What returns exactly the wrong value? `indexPath` (from `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]`) or the `strPOIndex`?

Comment: strPOIndex....indexPath is correct, its just always in the first section

Comment: You use `tableData`, but what's that? I'd suggest that you use the same mecanisme as in `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` (`sectionTitle`, `sectionContact`) to get your value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why your data source is different in cellforrow and prepare for segue. 
If you manage the same way as sections and rows.
You need to get data from datasource firstly by indexpath.section and then indexpath.row change this in prepareforsegue method.